# Migrate from ConfigRoot to ConfigMapping in quarkus extensions with a custom config prefix

Tags: java, quarkus, smallrye, quarkus-extension

**Problem**

We built our stack on top of quarkus and have several extensions with the `@ConfigRoot` class approach. We are now migrating to interfaces with `@ConfigMapping` as described in the Quarkus Extensions documentation.

We did all the configurations for our stack with a custom prefix (e.g. `mystack.`). We are now facing the problem that when using `@ConfigMapping` its not possible to use the same prefix for build and runtime configuration.

Having a shared prefix results in a config validation exception as the config loading mechanism validates that any configuration found can be mapped.

```
ERROR [io.qua.dep.dev.IsolatedDevModeMain] (main) Failed to start quarkus: io.smallrye.config.ConfigValidationException: Configuration validation failed:
        mystack.configKey does not map to any root
```

This is the intended behavior and is also described in the issue [Extension config for both build and run time with same prefix #32674](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/32674).

However, as many quarkus extensions share a prefix for build and runtime i've seen that sharing a configuration prefix is possible if it starts with `quarkus.` like `quarkus.mystack.` in our case.

**Question**

Is it possible to configure the config loading mechanism for the prefix `mystack.` with the same behavior as `quarkus.`?

If not - is splitting the runtime and buildtime config or moving to a prefix like `quarkus.mystack.` the only possible solution?

It seems like one of the key points for this behavior is the QuarkusConfigBuilderCustomizer ([source link](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/blob/main/core/runtime/src/main/java/io/quarkus/runtime/configuration/QuarkusConfigBuilderCustomizer.java#L102))

```
// Ignore unmapped quarkus properties, because properties in the same root may be split between build / runtime
builder.withMappingIgnore("quarkus.**");
```

Is there an easy way to add further prefixes to this list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, with the next Quarkus version (3.5.x), it is possible to register any number of `SmallRyeConfigBuilderCustomizer` to access the underlying Config builder and add additional mapping ignores for the custom prefix.

As a workaround, you can use `quarkus.config.mapping.validate-unknown=false` to disable the validation.

Comment: Thanks. This sounds promising. Is there any documentation available how to register custom ˋ SmallRyeConfigBuilderCustomizerˋ? Do you have an idea when 3.5 will be released?

Comment: For releases timelines check here: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/wiki/Release-Planning. For documentation check here: https://smallrye.io/smallrye-config/Main/config/customizer/